# How to construct a 2D Convolution matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convolution, image-processing

I have a problem in understanding this explanation stated in an article, which is as below:

$error = a-Bf$

where, vector $error$ is in lexicographic ordering, vector $a$ is a lexicographic ordering of a 2D dataset with dimension MxN, $f$ is a 2D filter with dimension KxL, and $B$ is the convolution matrix of a 2D dataset $b$. The dimension of $B$ is MNxKL.

Ok, I know that convolution can be rewritten as a Matrix-vector multiplication using the convolution matrix, here, matrix $B$. And, the dimension of $b$ is also MxN. In the above equation  $f$ should also be as a vector (probably also in lexicographic ordering).

What I do not understand is how this convolution matrix $B$ is constructed with this dimension? In 1D convolution we use Toeplitz to build the convolution matrix.

How does lexicographic ordering works in this problem?

Could you please give a small numeric example?

Comment: See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16798888/5802041).

Comment: Btw, if you use Matlab, there is a specific function "convmtx" which is more direct than using toeplitz form.

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, I know about `convmtx` for 1D convolution and `convmtx2` for 2D convolution, but, does it produce the same size convolution matrix as the one mentioned here?

Comment: 1) There is a certain "margin" in the choice of the size of a convolution matrix (either in 1D or 2D), depending for example of "trailing zeros" involved with boundaries issues 2) You might be interested by this [document](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.13367.pdf).